# Взять скриншот активити

Tags: android, java

Пытаюсь взять скриншот главного активити приложения и сохранить его, допустим на диск С. Что делаю не правильно? view - это, найденный по id в onCreate, основной LinearLayout.

```
public void screenShot() {
        View v = view.getRootView();
        v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap screen = v.getDrawingCache();
        String extr = "C://";
        File myPath = new File(extr, "ScreenShot!" + ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
            screen.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), screen, "Screen", "screen");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Какой еще диск С?????

Comment: =D ну да, тупанул

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.getFilesDir()
```

Сохраняй доя начала сюда и не разделяй имя и расширение файла, както эпично смотрится...

**ГЗВ**

где ты нашел способ так скринить?

```
Bitmap bitmap;
View v1 = view.getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: ок, спасибо))

Comment: сделал...
<pre>
String extr = this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
File myPath = new File(extr, "ScreenShot.jpg");
<code>

всё равно болт..

Comment: Лог кинь, я неиэкстрасенс

Comment: http://pastebin.com/S8gBZ5x0

Comment: Реально излеваешься.... )))

Comment: Ну чтоооо =D

Comment: обновил ответ... я про логи... нафига мне смотреть 900 строк технического лога? учись по чутьчуть сам их читать... или хотя бы ошибки выбирать...